# How to sample/fit distribution from/for bi-modal data

Tags: r, distributions, python, simulation, bimodal

The context is: I have a sequence of data, of which the histograms show a bi-modal pattern. My final goal is to sample from this sequence in a simulation project. Now we want to fit a parametric model (or two models) over the data. My question is

- Is fitting parametric distribution over bi-modal data a good choice if my final goal is to sample from the data? shall I sample directly from the data? If so is there anything I shall pay special attention due to the bi-modal nature
- If I want to fit parametric models, is there any python libraries doing such? Is there any way to automatically detect whether a sample is not uni-modal?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your data fits the so called [mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model). From wikipedia:

> In statistics, a mixture model is a probabilistic model for representing the presence of subpopulations within an overall population, without requiring that an observed data set should identify the sub-population to which an individual observation belongs

Answering your second point: There are some more [rigorous ways of testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution#General_tests). Usually multimodal data will have a larger variance so this may be a sign for a closer look. I know that this is not the best practice but often I've seen people visually inspecting to detect bimodal for instance.

One popular algorithm is the [EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) which is implemented, for instance, assuming that both distributions are gaussian in [GaussianMixture](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture) class of `scikit-learn`.

After fitting a GaussianMixture you can even call the [`sample()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/mixture/base.py#L399) method and get your samples.